Dovecot LMTP Crashing on Large Emails (Sieve Rules Suspected) - Ubuntu 22.04
I noticed errors in the incoming emails on my VPS over the past month, particularly with emails containing large attachments (>10 MB).
This issue seems to affect multiple mail users, resulting in emails being stuck in the mail queue for an extended period. I suspect that the problem may be related to the sieve rules in place.
# rule:[Sonstiges]
if header :contains "subject" ["hacker","hacking","Virus"]
{
    fileinto "Junk";
}

Removing this rule and then reloading doveadm has allowed the queued emails to be successfully delivered. The Junk folder exists. Emails that are stuck do not appear to include any of those strings.
The mail.err has plenty of entries like this:
Oct  8 11:04:16 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1578877><mDQkD471BGd9FxgAPVEKtg>: Panic: Buffer write out of range (0 + 1)
Oct  8 11:04:16 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1578877><mDQkD471BGd9FxgAPVEKtg>: Error: Raw backtrace: /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(backtrace_append+0x46) [0x7fa21a8fa0b6] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(backtrace_get+0x22) [0x7fa21a8fa1d2] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x109fab) [0x7fa21a906fab] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x10a047) [0x7fa21a907047] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5cfd3) [0x7fa21a859fd3] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5bec5) [0x7fa21a858ec5] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(buffer_write+0x22) [0x7fa21a8fc502] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_emit_integer+0x69) [0x7fa219e736c9] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_save+0x1fa) [0x7fa219e71d2a] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_file_update_resource_usage+0x115) [0x7fa219e733b5] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_close+0x7d) [0x7fa219e702bd] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so(+0x42b3) [0x7fa219f062b3] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-lda.so.0(mail_deliver+0x16e) [0x7fa21ab4b0fe] -> dovecot/lmtp(lmtp_local_default_deliver+0x1e8) [0x55a2aef1b408] -> dovecot/lmtp(lmtp_local_data+0x59a) [0x55a2aef1bb4a] -> dovecot/lmtp(client_default_cmd_data+0x191) [0x55a2aef1a4c1] -> dovecot/lmtp(cmd_data_continue+0x180) [0x55a2aef1a250] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x7c6d6) [0x7fa21a8796d6] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_call_io+0x6d) [0x7fa21a91d25d] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_handler_run_internal+0x13a) [0x7fa21a91e95a] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_handler_run+0x54) [0x7fa21a91d304] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_run+0x40) [0x7fa21a91d4c0] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(master_service_run+0x17) [0x7fa21a88f727] -> dovecot/lmtp(main+0x225) [0x55a2aef18ec5] -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7fa21a5f6d90] -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7fa21a5f6e40] -> dovecot/lmtp(_start+0x25) [0x55a2aef18fc5]
Oct  8 11:04:16 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1578877><mDQkD471BGd9FxgAPVEKtg>: Fatal: master: service(lmtp): child 1578877 killed with signal 6 (core dumped)
Oct  8 11:24:16 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1581353><ABWVEz76BGcpIRgAPVEKtg>: Panic: Buffer write out of range (0 + 1)
Oct  8 11:24:16 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1581353><ABWVEz76BGcpIRgAPVEKtg>: Error: Raw backtrace: /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(backtrace_append+0x46) [0x7ff19a6ca0b6] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(backtrace_get+0x22) [0x7ff19a6ca1d2] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x109fab) [0x7ff19a6d6fab] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x10a047) [0x7ff19a6d7047] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5cfd3) [0x7ff19a629fd3] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5bec5) [0x7ff19a628ec5] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(buffer_write+0x22) [0x7ff19a6cc502] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_emit_integer+0x69) [0x7ff199c436c9] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_save+0x1fa) [0x7ff199c41d2a] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_file_update_resource_usage+0x115) [0x7ff199c433b5] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_close+0x7d) [0x7ff199c402bd] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so(+0x42b3) [0x7ff199cd62b3] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-lda.so.0(mail_deliver+0x16e) [0x7ff19a91b0fe] -> dovecot/lmtp(lmtp_local_default_deliver+0x1e8) [0x56553f845408] -> dovecot/lmtp(lmtp_local_data+0x59a) [0x56553f845b4a] -> dovecot/lmtp(client_default_cmd_data+0x191) [0x56553f8444c1] -> dovecot/lmtp(cmd_data_continue+0x180) [0x56553f844250] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x7c6d6) [0x7ff19a6496d6] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_call_io+0x6d) [0x7ff19a6ed25d] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_handler_run_internal+0x13a) [0x7ff19a6ee95a] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_handler_run+0x54) [0x7ff19a6ed304] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_run+0x40) [0x7ff19a6ed4c0] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(master_service_run+0x17) [0x7ff19a65f727] -> dovecot/lmtp(main+0x225) [0x56553f842ec5] -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7ff19a3c6d90] -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7ff19a3c6e40] -> dovecot/lmtp(_start+0x25) [0x56553f842fc5]
Oct  8 11:24:16 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1581353><ABWVEz76BGcpIRgAPVEKtg>: Fatal: master: service(lmtp): child 1581353 killed with signal 6 (core dumped)
Oct  8 11:29:36 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1581993><JOt4M377BGepIxgAPVEKtg>: Panic: Buffer write out of range (0 + 1)
Oct  8 11:29:36 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1581993><JOt4M377BGepIxgAPVEKtg>: Error: Raw backtrace: /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(backtrace_append+0x46) [0x7f2655d310b6] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(backtrace_get+0x22) [0x7f2655d311d2] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x109fab) [0x7f2655d3dfab] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x10a047) [0x7f2655d3e047] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5cfd3) [0x7f2655c90fd3] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x5bec5) [0x7f2655c8fec5] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(buffer_write+0x22) [0x7f2655d33502] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_emit_integer+0x69) [0x7f26552aa6c9] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_save+0x1fa) [0x7f26552a8d2a] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_file_update_resource_usage+0x115) [0x7f26552aa3b5] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0(sieve_binary_close+0x7d) [0x7f26552a72bd] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so(+0x42b3) [0x7f265533d2b3] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-lda.so.0(mail_deliver+0x16e) [0x7f2655f820fe] -> dovecot/lmtp(lmtp_local_default_deliver+0x1e8) [0x561e7388b408] -> dovecot/lmtp(lmtp_local_data+0x59a) [0x561e7388bb4a] -> dovecot/lmtp(client_default_cmd_data+0x191) [0x561e7388a4c1] -> dovecot/lmtp(cmd_data_continue+0x180) [0x561e7388a250] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(+0x7c6d6) [0x7f2655cb06d6] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_call_io+0x6d) [0x7f2655d5425d] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_handler_run_internal+0x13a) [0x7f2655d5595a] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_handler_run+0x54) [0x7f2655d54304] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(io_loop_run+0x40) [0x7f2655d544c0] -> /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot.so.0(master_service_run+0x17) [0x7f2655cc6727] -> dovecot/lmtp(main+0x225) [0x561e73888ec5] -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f2655a2dd90] -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f2655a2de40] -> dovecot/lmtp(_start+0x25) [0x561e73888fc5]
Oct  8 11:29:36 km30738-03 dovecot: lmtp(user@example.com)<1581993><JOt4M377BGepIxgAPVEKtg>: Fatal: master: service(lmtp): child 1581993 killed with signal 6 (core dumped)

This is of my knowledge. But a "Panic: Buffer write out of range" sounds bad.
Additionally, users experiencing email delivery issues seem to have peculiar files stored in the sieve folder.
/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/user/sieve/active.svbin
/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/user/sieve/active.svbin.server.example.com.145195.e85d1a9cf9d99deb
/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/user/sieve/active.svbin.server.example.com.145802.95e76b65ac2b54cf
(…)
/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/user/sieve/active.svbin.server.example.com.148819.a656ae666826efeb

I am running dovecot version 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a) on Ubuntu 22.04. Despite the provider saying no configuration issues on their end, I am asked to investigate the email delivery issues.
